# How to add a counter about the total number of nodes visited by a user?

Tags: views, 7, users, nodes

I have one block that display individual user details.

How can I add a counter which counts the total number of nodes visited by a user?

Comment: What research have you done, what modules have you examined that meet your needs http://lmgtfy.com/?q=drupal+user+statistics+module

Comment: till now i have just given view statistics but that only for the node not for users

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked the **[Node view count](https://drupal.org/project/nodeviewcount)** module: Node View Count module allows to count node views.

> Unlike statistics module, this module records each view of node with
>   **user uid** and timestamp.

I guess at max. you only would have need to write the correct database query to get the count of total number of nodes visited by a user as rest of the things are being done by this module.

Comment: this module is only for the total number of times an individual node has been visited, but that we can also handle by statistics need not to use any module

Comment: @asalug yeah but this module stores each view of node with **user uid** and timestamp, from there you can get the distinct node ids corresponding to the required user within a required time, and getting a count of those node will provide you the required result.

Comment: so you saying that by using this module i can get total number of node visited by the individual user..right? wel let me try this if it work den a big thanks or please guide me how to use it which fulfill my requirement..thanks..

Comment: could not able to figure out how to use this please guide me.

Comment: First of all check the doc or the "README.txt" file of this module, after enabling the module configure it for the required content types than visite nodes and check in the database (in the table created by this module) the format of values getting stored, from there you will get the idea to write the database query in a manner to get you the required result.